# How can I solve this issue in javascript

Tags: javascript

I don't know what's wrong with my code. I want to create animation that goes from top to bottom.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
   
    <style>
        #box{
            width: 600px;
            height: 600px;
            position: relative;
            background: rgb(84, 116, 22);
        }
        #move{
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            background: rgb(31, 30, 30);
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="box">
            <div id="move"></div>
        </div>
        <button onclick="javascript:changeCSS();"  class="btn btn-dark mt-3">Change css</button>
    </div>    
    <script>
      function changeCSS(){
          var position=0, speed, changeCss;
          changeCss = document.querySelector('#move');
          speed= setInterval(repeat, 3);
          function repeat(){
            if(position=550){
                clearInterval(speed);
            }else{
                position++;
                changeCss.style.top=position;
                changeCss.style.left=position;
            }
          }
        }
            
    </script>
```

So, what is solution for this problem? I've been searching for 4 hours and yet, I can't find what is the problem. Maybe, it would be syntax problem, but there is no problem in console

By the way, why posting is so much difficult?

Comment: `=` is for assigning values, `==` and `===` are for making comparisons.

Comment: I would recommend against using JavaScript for animating, it is not good for performance. Look at [CSS animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) instead

Comment: Also I'd recommend you to look into [debugging with devtools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0XScE08hy8). If you had single-stepped through your code, you would have noticed that it always goes into the `if` and that `position` _changes_ to 550 when it does that, providing you a big hint about what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You used `=` in your if statement, this just assigend 550 to `position` and therefore was always `true`
2. You assigend a number to `style.top` and `style.left` which doesn't work. You need to provide a unit for css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    #box {
      width: 600px;
      height: 600px;
      position: relative;
      background: rgb(84, 116, 22);
    }
    
    #move {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      position: absolute;
      background: rgb(31, 30, 30);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="box">
      <div id="move"></div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="javascript:changeCSS();" class="btn btn-dark mt-3">Change css</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    function changeCSS() {
      let position = 0;
      const changeCss = document.querySelector('#move');
      const speed = setInterval(repeat, 3);

      function repeat() {
        if (position >= 550) {
          clearInterval(speed);
        } else {
          position++;
          changeCss.style.top = position + "px";
          changeCss.style.left = position + "px";
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
```

A better way would be to use css animations:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <style>
        #box {
          width: 600px;
          height: 600px;
          position: relative;
          background: rgb(84, 116, 22);
        }
        
        #move {
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          position: absolute;
          background: rgb(31, 30, 30);
        }
        
        #move.active {
          animation: moveAnimation 3s linear;
          top: 550px;
          left: 550px;
        }
        
        @keyframes moveAnimation {
          from {
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
          }
          to {
            top: 550px;
            left: 550px;
          }
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="box">
          <div id="move"></div>
        </div>
        <button onclick="javascript:changeCSS();" class="btn btn-dark mt-3">Change css</button>
      </div>
      <script>
        function changeCSS() {
          const changeCss = document.querySelector('#move');
          changeCss.classList.add("active");
        }
      </script>
```